# Sorting similar files according to a field in the filename and delete the old one

Tags: bash, shell, unix, solaris

I need your help on a topic. My problem is I want to sort files in a directory according to a field in the file name and delete the old one.

For example;
I have two files in a directory which look like below:

Created Date File Name

---

```
Jan 10 15:56 FileFormat_1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX_20180109.txt

Jan 10 16:40 FileFormat_1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX_20180110.txt
```

I need to split file name by `"_"` character and sort the files by two ID fields `("1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX")` and delete/move the older one.

Can you please help me to find a solution in a shell script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me. What is it that you really wish to do?  Do you have two files with same name `FileFormat_1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX_20180110.txt` inside a directory.? That sounds unlikely. Having said, that you should produce the minimum code sample in SO so that someone trying to help you could reproduce the issue. :-)

Comment: I'm sorry I typed file names wrongly.  Last part of the file name would be different. Like FileFormat_1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX_20180110 and FileFormat_1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX_20180109.

Comment: Then edit your question...

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of files sorted by key (in filenames) and file modification time (`%C@` to get the modification time, `%f` to get filename; change them to what you need):

```
$> find directory -printf '%C@ %f\n' | \
        sed -n -r '/_.*_/{s:^([^_]*)_(.*)_(.*)$:\2 \1_\2_\3:;p}' | \
        sort

1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX 1516178476.1838399230 FileFormat_1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX_20180110.txt
1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX 1516178479.7838400320 FileFormat_1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX_20180109.txt
1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX 1516178501.4338406770 FileFormat_1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX_20180111.txt
```

To get a list of UNIQUE files by key from that list (note: "unique" = take only the first one, so we need to reverse the order of that):

```
$> find directory -printf '%C@ %f\n' | \
        sed -n -r '/_.*_/{s:^([^_]*)_(.*)_(.*)$:\2 \1_\2_\3:;p}' | \
        sort -r | \
        sort -k1,1 -u 

1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX 1516178501.4338406770 FileFormat_1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX_20180111.txt
```

Now, you can move those selected files to another directory:

```
$> find directory -printf '%C@ %f\n' | \
     sed -n -r '/_.*_/{s:^([^_]*)_(.*)_(.*)$:\2 \1_\2_\3:;p}' | \
     sort -r | \
     sort -k1,1 -u | \
     sed -r 's:^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) (.*+)$:mv \"\3\" to-another-dir\/.:'

mv "FileFormat_1-IKRF2YZ_1-IKRF2YX_20180111.txt" to-another-dir/.
```

So this way, you can move all the latest files (ie. unique files) of each key to another directory; then, those files left can be deleted as you wish.

Comment: -printf option is not supported in my commadn. find: bad option -printf

Comment: I see, you are using Soralis while I am using Archlinux; sorry I can't help.